# React Relay always force fetch Route or RelayContainer

Tags: reactjs, relayjs

Is it possible to define that a relay container or a `<Route/>` to always forceFetch when (or before) mounting?

I could do a `this.props.relay.forceFetch()` in `componentDidMount`, but it's kinda ugly + does two requests if it's an initial page load.

Comment: Are you doing `forceFetch` because the data changes frequently? I mean are you trying to do so as a workaround for lack of subscription support?

Comment: @AhmadFerdous: consider the following interaction: show `<ListContainer/>`, navigate to `<ItemViewContainer/>`, go back to `<ListContainer/>`. I want to make sure that the data in ListContainer never is stale. Even if there was subscription support, I don't think that would solve this case.

Comment: I have same issue. Yes there is lack of subscription support but that is irrelevant. My server would not support it anyway. I need to re-poll data every time I render component. But not twice as it is happening now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more elegant solution is to use `Relay.Renderer forceFetch` which will pull new data from server regardless of the current data state of the component.
It can be used with react-relay-router like in docs:

```
<Router
    history={history}
    routes={routes}
    render={applyRouterMiddleware(useRelay)}
    forceFetch={true}
    environment={Relay.Store}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define fragment like that:

```
export default Relay.createContainer(Component, {
  initialVariables: { show: false },
  fragments: {
    viewer: (): string => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Viewer  {
        messages @include(if: $show) {
           id
        }
      }
    `,
  },
})
```

then

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.relay.forceFetch({ show: true })
}
```

This way component will only load once. And will always refetch when you remount it.
Please note that if this is a top level component you might get error because you are not fetching ANY data. 
I added request for user ID as a temporary hack it is resolved much faster by my graphql server.